# MongoDB connection refused, port 3001 reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, npm

MongoDB connection is being refused at port connection 3001, it was working before but suddenly it stopped working. My database is on MongoDB atlas. I am connected through mongoDB compass and I have the connection link in my code. I followed a mern tutorial exactly but am still facing this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7EDAR2GRVo. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [listOfUsers, setListOfUsers] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getUsers").then((response) => {
      setListOfUsers(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const createUser = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/createUser", {
      name,
      age,
      username,
    }).then((response) => {
      setListOfUsers([
        ...listOfUsers,
        {
          name,
          age,
          username,
        },
      ]);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="usersDisplay">
        {listOfUsers.map((user) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>Name: {user.name}</h1>
              <h1>Age: {user.age}</h1>
              <h1>Username: {user.username}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>

      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setName(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Age..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setAge(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setUsername(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={createUser}> Create User </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserModel = require("./models/Users");

const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.md4aag2.mongodb.net/merntutorial?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

app.get("/getUsers", (req, res) => {
    UserModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    })
});

app.post("/createUser", async (req, res) => {
    const user = req.body;
    const newUser = new UserModel(user);
    await newUser.save();
  
    res.json(user);
  });
  
  app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("SERVER RUNS PERFECTLY!");
  });
```

Comment: Posting credentials is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Search `services.msc` in your device and click start to run the `MongoDB` server.

After `start or restart` running MongoDB server, you will be able to run your program

Comment: I'm on a mac, do you know the equivalent on mac?

Comment: I checked and the server is running but it still won't connect. I think there is a problem with this connection link `mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.md4aag2.mongodb.net/merntutorial?retryWrites=true&w=majority`